# Using os.system to operate a .py file on many files

Tags: python, directory, os.system

I hope that I can ask this in a clear way, im very much a beginner to python and forums in general so I apologise if i've got anything wrong from the start!

My issue is that I am currently trying to use os.system() to enable a program to run on every file within a directory (this is a directory of ASCII tables which I am crossing with a series of other tables to find matches.

```
import os 

for filename in os.listdir('.'):
os.system('stilts tmatch2 ifmt1=ascii ifmt2=ascii in1=intern in2= %s matcher=2d values1='col1 col2' values2='col1 col2' params=5 out= %s-table.fits'%(filename,filename))
```

So what im hoping this would do is for every 'filename' it would operate this program known as stilts. Im guessing this gets interrupted/doesn't work because of the presence of apostrophes ' in the line of code itself, which must disrupt the syntax? (please correct me if I am wrong)

I then replaced the ' in os.system() with "" instead. This, however, stops me using the %s notation to refer to filenames throughout the code (at least I am pretty sure anyway).

```
import os 

for filename in os.listdir('.'):
os.system("stilts tmatch2 ifmt1=ascii ifmt2=ascii in1=intern in2= %s matcher=2d values1='col1 col2' values2='col1 col2' params=5 out= %s-table.fits"%(filename,filename))
```

This now runs but obviously doesn't work, as it inteferes with the %s input.

Any ideas how I can go about fixing this? are there any alternative ways to refer to all of the other files given by 'filename' without using %s?

Thanks in advance and again, sorry for my inexperience with both coding and using this forum!

Comment: I believe that if you use os.listdir() without any params you will have the list in the same folder as the python file, by using the (".") param what are you recieving?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with os.system() but maybe if you try do some changes about the string you are sending to that method before it could behave differently.

You must know that in python you can "sum" strings so you can save your commands in a variable and add the filenames as in:

```
os.system(commands+filename+othercommands+filename)
```

other problem that could be working is that when using:

```
for file in os.listdir()
```

you may be recievin file types instead of the strings of their names. Try using a method such as filename.name to check if this is a different type of thing.

Sorry I cant test my answers for you but the computer I am using is too slow for me to try downloading python.